# Including Propel without Composer

Tags: php, git, propel

The Propel ORM's [installation instructions](http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html#via-git) say that you can setup the ORM by cloning its Git repository. I have done that but I have no idea how to include Propel into my project.

Since I'm not using Composer, I don't have an `autoload.php` file to include, and `src/Propel/Runtime/Propel.php` is clearly not the only thing that I need to include, although some have suggested that it is.

Does anyone know how to include Propel without using Composer's `autoload.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Propel comes with its own autoloader. You can use it in the steps.
`require '/absolute/path/to/Propel.php;`
`Propel::init('/path/to/yourdbname-conf.php);` where you'd name is the value of the "name" attribute of the database element in the schema.xml file. 
`set_include_path('/path/to/folder/for/generated/models' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path();`